# create or edit models and tables dynamically based on user input from a form outside admin panel

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am new to python django and I wanted to ask if there is a suggested way to create an app with ui for the users to be able to create tables on database with models dynamically.

So basically I want the user to fill in the table name and desired column names with types on a form and create them dynamically when they hit submit button. this is for an internal application where we do not want to use the admin panel for implementing it as admin panel will have other elements needed.

any advise or examples shared to take a look and learn along the road building would be a huge help.

Thank you so much for all the support.

Comment: I think you're wanting a NoSQL database, because there is no schema to be followed. Search some of those and find a way to integrate with Django.

Comment: Hi Bernando - I want to use oracle database as a backend for our app

Comment: also, came across this one.. but could not find any examples on how to implement :( https://pypi.org/project/django-mutant/

Comment: It's repository looks abandoned, 3 years for the last commit, and they only assert to support django until 1.9

Comment: any other alternatives or suggestions would be of great help.. pls advise

Comment: Nothing comes to mind ;/  I believe that a hybrid database solution could be the best one here, using both RDB(Oracle) and NoSQL

Comment: any advise if this would help? https://pypi.org/project/django-dynamic-model/